# Variables between index.html and app.js

Tags: javascript, html

I request a username using a prompt within my index.html. My code looks like this:

```
<script>
      // YOU DO NOT NEED TO EDIT THIS CODE
      if (!/(&|\?)username=/.test(window.location.search)) {
        var newSearch = window.location.search;
        if (newSearch !== '' & newSearch !== '?') {
          newSearch += '&';
        }
        var username = prompt('What is your name?') || 'anonymous';
        console.log("From Index.html:" , username);
        newSearch += 'username=' + (username);
        window.location.search = newSearch;
      }
    </script>
```

I need to access this username within my app.js. I am sending a POST request to a server that requires the username as a property. For example:

```
      //POST the message to the server
  handleSubmit: function() {
    var query = window.location.search;
    var username = query.slice(10, query.length);
    var room = $('#roomSelect').find(':selected').text();
    var msg = {
      username: username,
      text: $('#message').val(),
      roomname: room
    };
    app.send(msg);
    console.log(msg);
    app.renderMessage(msg);
  }
```

Essentially, I want to prompt the user for their username in the index.html, but how do I access this variable from the app.js? Do I send it back to that file somehow?

Comment: Including both js in the same page, in the correct order, should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

You can try it to store in session variable and then access it from anywhere

Hope this will help you
Thanks!!!